# Java Center image and create green border

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a Java in BlueJ that will have a traffic light change with button clicks i.e., green turn to green, yellow turn to yellow, and so on...

My current image puts the location of the lights in the upper left corner. 
 I would like to center the lights and buttons as I am also trying to add in a thick green boarder around the image as well.  However, Anytime I try to move the image it flips it horizontally or if I add in a green boarder it turns into a box beside the lights.  I'm also trying to move the buttons to be above the traffic lights vs. below the lights.

Could I have some assistance with:
Adding in the green border,
centering the Lights within the border and moving the buttons to the top of the lights (also centered within border)

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class TrafficLight extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton b1, b2, b3;

  Signal green = new Signal(Color.green);
  Signal yellow = new Signal(Color.yellow);
  Signal red = new Signal(Color.red);

public TrafficLight(){
    super("Traffic Light");
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    b1 = new JButton("Red");
    b2 = new JButton("Yellow");
    b3 = new JButton("Green");
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);        

    green.turnOn(false);
    yellow.turnOn(false);
    red.turnOn(true);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    p1.add(red);
    p1.add(yellow);
    p1.add(green);
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    p2.add(b1);
    p2.add(b2);
    p2.add(b3);

    getContentPane().add(p1);
    getContentPane().add(p2);
    pack();
    }


public static void main(String[] args){
    TrafficLight tl = new TrafficLight();        
    tl.setVisible(true);
}    
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){        
    if (e.getSource() == b1){
        green.turnOn(false);            
        yellow.turnOn(false);
        red.turnOn(true);
    } else if (e.getSource() == b2){
        yellow.turnOn(true);            
        green.turnOn(false);
        red.turnOn(false);
    } else if (e.getSource() == b3){
        red.turnOn(false);            
        yellow.turnOn(false);
        green.turnOn(true);
    }
}
}     
class Signal extends JPanel{

Color on;
int radius = 40;
int border = 10;
boolean change;

Signal(Color color){
    on = color;
    change = true;
}

public void turnOn(boolean a){
    change = a;
    repaint();        
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    int size = (radius+border)*2;
    return new Dimension( size, size );
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor( Color.black );
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

    if (change){
        g.setColor( on );
    } else {
        g.setColor( on.darker().darker().darker() );
    }
    g.fillOval( border,border,2*radius,2*radius );
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like Java and not  javascript ;)

Comment: Thank you Marcel I've updated the comment section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adding in the green border,

Add a Border to the panel. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)

> centering the Lights

Easiest way is to use a "wrapper" panel for your traffic light panel:

```
//getContentPane().add(p1);
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( p1 );
add( wrapper );
```

The default layout for a `JPanel` is the `FlowLayout` center aligned. So the traffic lights will remain centered as the frame size is changed.

> moving the buttons to the top of the lights

Don't use a GridLayout. The JFrame uses a `BorderLayout` by default. Just use that layout. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) to determine which constraint should be used with each panel.